# Object Empty after adding values Axios

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, callback, axios

I am new to javascript and need help in fixing this. I read many articles but couldn't fix this, can someone correct my code. 
Here,
links = an array of URLs containing javascript code, 
response = the javascript code present at that URL

```
 var code = {}

links.forEach(url => {
       axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
                  code[`file${i++}.js`] = response.data
             })
             .catch(err => {
                  console.error(err)
             })
});

// Come here only when the above loop has finished execution
//  dosomething with variable code

console.log(code)
```

When I print variable code, it is an empty object. I want to collect all values in the code object and then proceed further.

Note- I want to proceed execution next when the above loop is finished.

Comment: Do you want to use code in the same function or pass it to some other function

Comment: I want to use 'code'  in the same function. I am new to this, what you suggest?

Comment: The problem is that `axios.get` runs asynchronously. Thus the console.log of `code` gets executed before the `.then` callback is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an async call to populate the object, the data won't be available if you print immediately after the loop.

You should make use of async-await with Promise.all

```
async function someFunc() {
...

    try {

        var code = {}

        const promises = links.map(url => {
               return axios.get(url)
                    .then(response => {
                          code[`file${i++}.js`] = response.data
                     })
                     .catch(err => {
                          console.error(err)
                     })
        });
        await Promise.all(promises);

        console.log(code)

    }catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: So, If I want to use 'code' further then I have to write all my logic inside try block or I can write outsde someFunc() call?

Comment: Yes you need to have all your logic in try block. you could return the result from this function and use it in another, but there also you would need to have async-await